# MySQL Procedure Prepare and Execute error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a working procedure:

```
   drop procedure if exists parents;
   create procedure parents(in related int(11),out counted int(11))
   begin
    drop temporary table if exists ids;
    create temporary table ids(id int(11));
    while related<>0 do
     select category.related into related from category where category.id=related;
     insert into ids(id) values(related);
    end while;
    select count(*) into counted from ids;
   end;
```

But I want to create a dynamic tablename. So I would like to build something like so:

```
   drop procedure if exists parents;
   create procedure parents(in related int(11),name varchar(22),out counted int(11))
   begin
    drop temporary table if exists ids;
    create temporary table ids(id int(11));
    while related<>0 do
     prepare statement from concat("select t.related into related from ",name," t where t.id=?");
     execute statement using related;
     insert into ids(id) values(related);
    end while;
    select count(*) into counted from ids;
   end;
```

But I get an error boolean error.

Comment: What is the data type of `related` column in that `named` table???

Comment: int(11) default null